# Integration of a trig function

Tags: integration, trigonometry

How would the following trig function be integrated.

$$\int \cot^{2}x\csc^{2}x$$

I did

$$\int(\csc^{2}x-1)\csc^{2}x$$

But I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: That’s not what you want to do. Try the substitution $u=\cot x$.

Comment: Hmm so If I have $u=cot(x)$, $du=-csc^2(x)$ what about the $cot^2(x)$ in the problem $cot^2(x)csc^2(x)$

Comment: Oh I think I see you would get $-\frac{\cot^{3}x}{3}+c$

Comment: @Fernando: If you see it as $u^2$, you’re right!

Comment: Yes I did use $u^2$ yes yes many thanks

Comment: @Fernando: You’re welcome!